# Fetch mysql inserted data from yesterday 14:00 till now

Tags: mysql

I am writing a php page and I want to fetch all rows inserted in mysql table from yesterday at 14:00 till current time, I tried many queries and functions in mysql but it didn't help, appreciate any help in this regard.

regards,

Comment: Do you record a timestamp when you insert a row?

Comment: no, eventually the query should go back to one day before and fetch all records inserted from the time 14:00

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your issue? If so, please accept the answer.  If not, let me know what you still need and I'll see what I can do to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the right answer

```
WHERE updated_at >= concat(subdate(CURDATE(), 1),' 09:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not automatically keep track of when a row is inserted. You will need to add a column to your table with a `datetime` data type to keep track of this information. When you insert a record use the `now ()` function to populate the field. Then use the `between...and` syntax in the `where` clause of your `select` queries. You may also want to use the `current time ()` function in your where clause. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/
For examples and details.